# Accessing Private Methods from Module Functions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module

I'm trying to create private helper methods for module functions to no avail. I feel like there's something very simple I'm missing.

***Updated example with a more understandable use case:***

```
module FancyScorer
  module_function

  def score(ary)
    scores = []
    ary.each_slice(2).with_index do |slice, i|
      scores <<
        case i % 2
        when 0
          score_eventh(ary)
        else
          score_oddth(ary)
        end
    end
    scores.inject(:+)
  end

  private

  def score_eventh(ary)
    ary.inject(:+) / (ary.size - 1)
  end

  def score_oddth(ary)
    ary.inject(:*) / (ary.size - 1)
  end
end

FancyScorer.score([1,2,3,4])
# => `block in score_curiously': undefined method `score_eventh'
#    for FancyScorer:Module (NoMethodError)
```

*Note: The private methods should remain private.*

Here's the use case: there are several modules that contain various scoring techniques, e.g. `FancyScorer`, `SimpleScorer`, `ComplexScorer`. These functions are tested independently, and then are employed to create a `score` method for different classes.  For instance:

```
class A
  ...
  def score    
    FancyScorer.score(metrics) + 2*SimpleScorer.score(metrics)
  end
end

class B
  ...
  def score
    0.5*FancyScorer.score(metrics) + 2*SimpleScorer.score(metrics[0,3]) + ComplexScorer.score(metrics)
  end
end
```

***Previous example with no provided use case:***

```
module Party
  module_function

  def pooper
    enjoy
  end

  private

  def enjoy
    puts "Wahoo!"
  end
end

Party.pooper
# => NameError: undefined local variable or method `enjoy' for Party:module
#            from (party): in `pooper`
```

Comment: You have a bit of an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) here. You should explain your actual problem. It's abnormal to call methods directly on a module.

Comment: The example presented was very contrived. I'm implementing the design pattern promoted by Corey Haines and Gary Bernhardt (what Bernhardt calls "functional core and imperative shell"), and in certain cases I require the namespace to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @faraz Did you get now?

Comment: @faraz okay, so you're trying to namespace some things. The code paste you have doesn't demonstrate that at all. Why don't you demonstrate a conflict you're trying to avoid so that someone can help you get a proper, idiomatic solution?

Comment: @naomik Fast, simple question to ask. I didn't feel it necessary to convolute the example with a specific use case. You're entirely right about the potential for abuse. I'll update the question for posterity's sake in due time.

Comment: **Now don't change this original post**. If you change the total answer will be useless. If you have new confusions,post a new question. I answered as per the above post,not your changed one.

Comment: I promised @naomik a more thorough example of the use case. The question remains unchanged: "I'm trying to create ***private*** helper methods for module functions."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**`module_function(symbol, ...) → self`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-module_function) says:-

> Creates module functions for the named methods. ***These functions may be called with the module as a receiver,*** and also become available as instance methods to classes that mix in the module. Module functions are copies of the original, and so may be changed independently. The instance-method versions are made private. If used with no arguments, subsequently defined methods become module functions.

You need to make sure you declare the helper method as a `#private_class_method`:  `private` only affects instance methods.

```
module Party

  def enjoy
    puts 'hello'
  end

  def pooper
    enjoy
  end

  private_class_method :enjoy
  module_function :pooper
end

Party.pooper # => 'hello'
Party.enjoy # => private method `enjoy' called for Party:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Furthermore, you should be careful about the ordering of accessibility keywords like `public`, `private`, and `module_function`. **These do not overlap, but rather override.**

```
module Party
  module_function # Module function declarations begin
  def pooper
    bar
  end
  def bar
    enjoy
  end

  private         # Private declarations begin, module function declarations end
  module_function # Private declarations end, module function declarations begin
  def enjoy       # Therefore, this is a module function
    "Wahoo!"
  end
end

Party.pooper # => "Wahoo!"
Party.bar # => "Wahoo!"
Party.enjoy # => "Wahoo!"  <-- No longer private
```

Note here `module_function` overrides the previous `private` declaration.

---

***Here some more examples  when `module_function` will do its job, and when not.***

The `module_function` definitions stop once another accessibility keyword pops up. In this example, `module_function` is interrupted by `public` making `#pooper` a public instance method. Use of `private` would similarly block `module_method`.

```
module Party
  module_function
  public
  def pooper
    "i am pooper"
  end
end

Party.pooper
# undefined method `pooper' for Party:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Now if the order is changed:

```
module Party
  public
  module_function
  def pooper
    "i am pooper"
  end
end

Party.pooper # => "i am pooper"
```

Comment: I wasn't even aware of a `Module#module_function` but I'm can't say I'm surprised. This is a working solution, but it seems like very bad module composition. (ps. I understand this is not your fault as this is what the OP is asking for)

Comment: @naomik `module_function` is very interesting.. please read the doc,you can understand why is this method..It has many many flavors..

Comment: after reading the docs, I'm even more frightened by it now. `module_function` seems like a great way to fragment the consistency of your module's behavior and add heaps of complexity. I'd have to have a real compelling reason to resort to using it.

Comment: @naomik humm.. Its a great method.. indeed :)

Comment: @naomik You should watch the [Haines' screencast](https://vimeo.com/30893836) ([summary](http://fespinoza.github.io/blog/2013/03/29/talk-review-fast-rails-tests/)), listen to a [relevant discussion](http://rubyrogues.com/067-rr-gary-bernhardts-testing-style/).

Comment: @faraz I learnt today a new thing from your post,so *+1* to you.. :) thanks to bring up this post here is SO.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit It looks like this exposes the private methods too. :( `Party#enjoy` is still callable.

Comment: @faraz I don't understand your confusions.. didn't recommend you to use this method.. I just told you how `module_function` does work.

Comment: The private methods should remain private. Once you declare them as module function, they become part of the public interface. In your first example, `#enjoy` is declared as private, but subsequently declaring `module_function :enjoy` seems to override that: `Party.enjoy` is now executable.

Comment: I did not change the question:  ***"I'm trying to create private helper methods for module functions."*** I only updated the example.  Things are not working as expected: I should not be able to access private functions from the public interface...  but I can.  See your first example: `Party#enjoy` is declared as private, meaning I should not be able to call `Party.enjoy` from the public interface. The method should only be accessible from the `pooper` method like any private method.

Comment: why you are not posting your new question and keep **changing** the original post. You made one accepted answer by you as unaccepted. This answer(**effort**) was totally made by your original and old post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39668/discussion-between-faraz-and-arup-rakshit)